# Include library path in the makefile

Tags: makefile

My makefile looks as follows

```
program_NAME := myprogram
program_C_SRCS := $(wildcard *.cc)
program_C_OBJS := ${program_C_SRCS:.cc=.o}
program_OBJS := $(program_C_OBJS) 
program_INCLUDE_DIRS := ../INCLUDE
program_LIBRARY_DIRS := 
program_LIBRARIES :=
CPPFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

.PHONY: all clean distclean

all: $(program_NAME)

$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
$(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)

clean:
    @- $(RM) $(program_NAME)
    @- $(RM) $(program_OBJS)

distclean: clean
```

I have created a library `stack.a` in some path `/home/Desktop/kk/stack`.
I want to include this library into my makefile so that during linking it should be picked up from that path.

I tried to give:

```
program_LIBRARY_DIRS := /home/Desktop/kk/stack
```

and in linking step I gave:

```
$(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) stack.a -o $(program_NAME)
```

But the makefile is not able to pick up the library from the path mentioned.

Instead, if I directly give:

```
$(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) /home/Desktop/kk/stack/stack.a -o $(program_NAME)
```

it works perfectly.

Please help me how to include this library path so that I do not have to give the location of library in link command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-L` link option only applies to libraries named `libX.a` or `libX.so` and linked using `-lX`, for some string `X`.  You would need to rename `stack.a` to `libstack.a` and refer to it in the link command as `-lstack`.

(You should also, ideally, put that in the `program_LIBRARIES` definition and use that in the `$(LINK.cc)` line.)

Comment: Thanks geekosaur !!! In the above makefile,I have renamed the library as you suggested and put the directory location whre the library exists in program_LIBRARY_DIRS then its working fine. But when I am keeping the library address in program_LIBRARIES := ../stack/libstack.a. Whats the difference between these two -l and -L options ? And if I am giving the absolute address of the library in program_LIBRARIES then why is it failing ..please clarify...Thanks

Comment: `program_LIBRARIES := -lstack` is how you should be using it, if you renamed it and you added the correct `-L` path option to `program_LIBRARY_DIRS`.